# how can i do For Loop Properly

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, swift4, programming-languages

I want to add  " 5 " in my arrays in every 3rd position

```
var myList: [String] = ["U.S", "Spain", "China", "Brazil", "India" , "Canada", "Germany", "UK", "Dubai", "Russia", "Japan", "Italy", "France", "Australia", "Thailand", "Mexico"]

var i = 0
for name in 0...myList.count {
    i = i + 1
    if  i % 3 == 0 {
        myList.insert("\(5)", at: i )
    }
}
print("\(myList)")
```

OutPut is:

```
["U.S", "Spain", "China", "5", "Brazil", "India", "5", "Canada", "Germany", "5", "UK", "Dubai", "5", "Russia", "Japan", "5", "Italy", "France", "Australia", "Thailand", "Mexico"]
```

but after 16 position in array , I am not able to put all 5 in my arrays because of arrays that is myList have total 16 counts  ....so how I can able to put 5 in my Arrays properly

Comment: `0...myList.count` this will crash, because for an array of size `myList.count`, the last valid index is `myList.count - 1`, not `myList.count`, as you're trying to access here. Also, if you need to iterate an array and access both the indices and the elements, use `for (offset, element) in array.enumerated() { ... }`. See my blog post about it for more info: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md#iterating-over-the-elements-and-maintaining-a-counter

Comment: Also, you can use `i.isMultiple(of: 3)` to more clearly express the same thing as `i % 3 == 0`. [`BinaryInteger.isMultiple(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/3126998-ismultiple) was [introduced in Swift 5](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md).

Comment: And by the way, what exactly are you trying to do with this? It's quite odd, why are numbers and countries in the same array? Is this just a toy example?

Comment: actually i am doing a project for my own practice ...and i am new to swift , you can say me a noob...so my challemge was to put a advertise in TableView Cell in every 3rd  or 4th position of table View ...so what i will do is if the value of array[indexpath.row].valueNO==5..than i will return the advertise cell....i know it is not the best practice for an expert like you ..but for just practicing purpose ,i m doing this..bcoz i m new n want to learn by practicing n trying new things..N by the way the reason i give the Country and Number Example is because i want to ask question in a simple way

Comment: That seems like great practice, actually, but it'll get quite complicated if you're using a raw `Array<String>` to store all this. I suggest you make a `TableRowDataSource` protocol, and two structs: a `CountryRowData` and a `AdvertisementRow`, which both conform to that protocol. The `CountryRowData` stores the country name, and any other country related stuff (flag, population, whatever), and a `AdvertisementRow` stores whatever data is necessary to drive an advertisement.

Comment: that seems like a good logic...will deifinitely try your one also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem there is that you are mutating the array (changing its elements while iterating it), so what you actually need to do is to insert your elements in reverse order. Try like this:

```
var myList = ["U.S", "Spain", "China", "Brazil", "India", "Canada", "Germany", "UK", "Dubai", "Russia", "Japan", "Italy", "France", "Australia", "Thailand", "Mexico" ]

for index in myList.indices.dropFirst().reversed() where index % 3 == 0 {
    myList.insert("5", at: index)
}

print(myList)   // "["U.S", "Spain", "China", "5", "Brazil", "India", "Canada", "5", "Germany", "UK", "Dubai", "5", "Russia", "Japan", "Italy", "5", "France", "Australia", "Thailand", "5", "Mexico"]\n"
```

Comment: @yuvi1234 most of my knowledge came from interacting with other users at SO. You just need to start trying to answer as many questions as possible, this will allow you to receive plenty feedback on your code which will help you improving it.